# A simple question on limits

Tags: calculus, limits

Does the following equation hold:

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} x^x = \left(\lim_{x\to\infty} x\right)^{\!x}?$$

I know that

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} x^n = \left(\lim_{x\to\infty} x\right)^{\!n}$$

holds if $n$ is different from $x$, but I am not sure if it holds where $n=x$.

Comment: No, because the $x$ in the exponent is also going to $\infty$

Comment: @Botond Thanks, but what if $x$ was going to a specific value, say $a$?

Comment: Well if you take $x$ going to $0$ you get $1=0^0 $ and RHS is undefined

Comment: if $x$ is $a$, it will not go to infinity

Comment: @HCP16 Thank you, then what if $0<a$ is different from infinity?

Comment: You are basically just taking out the $x$ in the exponent from the limit. You can't do that.

Comment: @Botond: I don't understand your remark (nor the upvotes): all these limits (but the top right - which is meaningless) diverge to infinity, and having $x$ instead of $n$ doesn't make it different.

Comment: I think the following is true:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x^x=\lim_{x\to\infty}(\lim_{x\to\infty}x)^x$$

Comment: @YvesDaoust I was talking about his first limit: $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} x^x = (\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} x)^x$. Basically, he just "took out" one $x$ from the limit. I've almost told you to check the top answer, it explains better what I was trying to point out (The $x$ in the exponent is "going somewhere" in the LHS, but it is not in the RHS (in the exponent)) - But I've just realized that it's your answer.

Answer (score 2):

A notation like

$$\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}x\right)^x$$ is twice meanigless because

- $x$ is used both as an independent variable (the exponent) and a dummy variable (argument of the limit), so which is which is ambiguous;
- the limit diverges so that raising it to a power is not defined.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have one more question. If $$ \lim_{x\to\infty} (f(x))^{x}=a $$ where $f(x)$ is function of $x$ and $a$ constant(so the limit is convergent), can we say $$  \lim_{x\to\infty} (f(x))=a^{1/x}?  $$ holds?

Comment: @BrightChancellor: same mistake. You didn't learn.

Comment: @BrightChancelor, you may write $$\begin{aligned}\lim_{x\to\infty}|f(x)|^x&=|a|^{\frac1x}\\\iff e^{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x\ln(|f(x)|)}&=e^{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x\ln(|a|)},\end{aligned}$$ but that works if certian conditions are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the same.

We have two expressions here.$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x^x$$

and $$ \left(\lim_{x\to\infty} x\right)^{\!x}$$

The first expression makes perfect sense and the answer is $$\lim_{x\to\infty} x^x =  \infty $$

The second expression is ambiguous.

You have   $$\lim_{x\to\infty} x =\infty$$ and you want to raise it to power of  $x$.

We have to know what is $x$ here to make an inference about $(\infty )^x.$

Of course we get a different answer for positive $x$ and for negative $x$.

Thus $$ \left(\lim_{x\to\infty} x\right)^{\!x}$$ depends on $x$.

Answer (score -1):

limit is similar to function, when you take limit, you let $x$ go to a specific point, or infinity, and you will get a exactly ONE answer if limit exist.( limit is unique if the space is Hausdorff, $R^n$ is Hausdorff).

I will slightly modify your question to :

$\lim_{x\to\infty} (\frac{1}{x}) ^x = (\lim_{x\to\infty} (\frac{1}{x}))^{x}$?

if we calculate the limit, we have   $0=0^x$.

for the right hand side of the equality, without any information on $x$, we cannot compute anything.